# Is it normal for my Measurement ID to appear in source code?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I just started to use Google Analytics 4 for my website. I used "Add new on-page tag" option to start using analytics. I copied and pasted code which google gave me to my head section. Then I realized when I use show source code option in my browser, I can see my Measurement ID.

Is it normal? When I watched some videos on youtube about google analytics, they were hiding their Measurement ID. I think I am doing this wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal. Probably in the videos they hide it to make it clear that that is the ID and not to send hits there, but if you look at any website with Google Analytics you can see the ID in the source or in the inspector.

Comment: Oh, thank you. What if someone copy code and use it in their website?

Comment: It happens that hits will be sent to that Property, so I suggest to set a filter in Analytics to include hits only from your hostname.

Comment: Okay, I see. Is there any way to hide my <script> codes? I thought to put them in a external js file but there is a outsourced js file within my ID again.

Comment: It is better to avoid it, as it would be recoverable anyway...